# Multiple parameters as http request Data in angular 4

Tags: angular

Please tell me how to send multiple request parameters as data for HTTP with multiple input forms in angular 4

thanks in Advance

Comment: Can't you send model object as json

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Just send it as array of object in key value pair like this

```
CreateMethod(input:HTMLInputElement){ 
  let firstName = {title:input.value} 
  input.value = ''; 
  let arrayYouNeedToSend = [{title:input.value}];
  this.http.post(this.url,JSON.stringify(arrayYouNeedToSend))
    .subscribe(response=>{ 
      //firstName.id=response.json().id; this.postvalue.splice(0,0,firstName); console.log(response.json()); 
    })
```

Comment: hey this is my Create method code


CreateMethod(input:HTMLInputElement){
   
  
     let firstName ={title:input.value}
     input.value='';
this.http.post(this.url,JSON.stringify(firstName))
.subscribe(response=>{
// firstName.id=response.json().id;
this.postvalue.splice(0,0,firstName);
  console.log(response.json());
})

how to pass as a array here , i am new to Angular